# How to realize the ObjectInputStream::read function's return value

Tags: java, io, objectinputstream

When using Java socket to transfer a file, I set `byte[] BUFFER = new byte[1024 * 8]`, and using `objectInputStream.read(BUFFER, 0, BUFFER.length)` to receive file stream, but the return value of `objectInputStream.read(BUFFER, 0, BUFFER.length)` is always 1024, Why would it be `1024` not `1024 * 8`.

[image]

the BUFFER length is 1024 * 8

[image]

but len is 1024.

Comment: Why are you using an `ObjectInputStream` to begin with if you're transferring byte arrays? An `ObjectInputStream` should only be used if you want to use the Java binary serialization format to transfer **objects**. As an aside, calling `flush` after each write makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `read` returns at most 1024 is because an `ObjectInputStream` internally uses a buffer of 1024 bytes (though this is an implementation detail, so it might be different in different versions or distributions of Java). A `read` is not required to return the requested number of bytes, so an `ObjectInputStream` will return either what is available in its current buffer, or request 1024 bytes from its upstream input stream and return that.

However, as I also mentioned in the comments, judging by the fragment of code you show in your question, you should probably not be using an `ObjectInputStream` at all. You're transferring binary data obtained with `read`, which means you're not using Java serialization in the code shown. Maybe you should switch to using normal input and output streams instead (that said, maybe you do use serialization at an earlier point, though combining serialization and normal binary transfer in a single stream is generally odd to do).

Comment: Thanks for that, the reason is I need to trans file's other information also before to trans byte arrays. And the file's other information is a java bean named `FileTransModel` which contains fileName, fileLength and other things about the file. so I use ObjectInputStream::readObject to receive the bean. To resolve the problem, If it is ok that I consider to use ObjectInputStream to read bean and DataInputStream to read byte arrays.

Comment: @KrlinHomon Using `DataInputStream` to read byte arrays doesn't make much sense either if you're not going to use any of the features of a `DataInputStream`. Use a normal input stream for that. That said, you can continue to use `ObjectInputStream`, but you'll have to accept the fact you can only read in blocks of 1024 bytes. In that case, reduce the size of your buffer and remove the call to `flush()` after each write so you actually benefit from the buffer of your buffered output stream!

Comment: Learned, thank you very much